# TypeError: object.__new__() takes no parameters when using generators

Tags: python-3.x

I am a newbie in python.I need to print all the numbers from 1 to 100.When i run this code,i got this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Eclipse\workspace\firstpython\src\oopsegmant.py", line 14, in <module>
 p = Prime(1)
TypeError: object.__new__() takes no parameters
```

The program is like this

```
class Prime():
    def _init_(self,i):
        self.i=i

def print_value(self):          
    while(True):
        yield(self.i)
        self.i+=self.i
p = Prime(1)
for numb in p.print_value():
    if(numb>100):
       break
    print(numb)
```

Comment: Just an aside - you could write that as: `for numb in itertools.islice(itertools.count(1), 100):`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`_init_` should be spelled with double underscores, `__init__`.

All special methods names are enclosed in double underscores.

Also the `print_value` method should be indented under the `class` to be a part of it.